# How many ways can 6 cars ( 3 pink, 2 orange and 1 yellow) be parked in 6 parking slots in a row?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

a. If the pink cars must be park together? - my answer is 4!3! or 144

b. If the orange cars must not be parked together?

c. If you can't park the yellow on either end?

d. If a pink car must be on both ends?

b,c,d is quite confusing tho

Cars of the same color are distinguishable.

Comment: Are cars of a particular color (say, pink) distinct or identical ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I can't particularly answer your question sir but they just give it like that. Idk if it distinct or identical sir. Maybe just base it on their colors.

Comment: Ok, suppose we assume that. Your 1st ans is incorrect. How did you get it ?

Comment: @trueblueanil I considered 3 pink as one, then 1 orange, 1 orange then 1 yellow so 4!

Then the 3! is came from the 3 pink

Comment: There are $3!$ ways to arrange the pink cars within their group of three if the cars are all distinguishable. If the pink cars are considered to all be the same then there is only one way to arrange pink cars within their own group of three: pink, pink, pink. You may want to look at earlier problem statements and their solutions to see which interpretation is meant by this wording in this particular book.

Comment: I thought we were taking cars of the same color as identical. So for part (a), the objects are {3 pink cars together}, 2 orange cars, 1 yellow, so 4!/2! because we can't distinguish between permutations of the yellow cars. Check the answer before proceeding further, because if each car is distinct, in any case all your answers will become incorrect.

Comment: @Robert  The answer you gave for part (a) is correct if each car is distinct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sir Yes distinct is the right term for this one. How can it be for b,c,d if its distinct?

Comment: @trueblueanil The answer would be distinct sir. How to answer this if its distinct?

Answer (score 2):

Treating the cars as distinct, here is another approach:

(a) you have solved correctly.

(b) permute non-orange cars in 4! ways, and place the orange cars in the gaps in between including end gaps:  *_C_C_C_C_* in $5\cdot4$ ways to get $20\cdot4!$ ways

(c) again, permute non-yellow cars in 5! ways and the yellow in the 4 *in-between* gaps *C_C_C_C_C*, to get 4*5! ways

(d) last one given without explanation: $_3P_2 \times 4!$ ways

Comment: What is $_3P_2$?

Comment: P is for permutations. There is no separate symbol for permutations. $_3P_2 = {3\choose 2}\cdot 2!$

Answer (score 0):

Since cars of the same color are distinguishable, your answer for (a) is correct.

To determine the number of ways the cars can be parked if the two orange cars are not adjacent, we subtract the number of arrangements in which they are adjacent from the total number of arrangements.  There are $6!$ ways to park six distinct cars in a row.  If the orange cars were together, there would be five objects to arrange (the block of two orange cars and the other four cars), which can be done in $5!$ ways.  Since the two orange cars can be arranged in $2!$ ways, there are $5!2!$ arrangements in which the two orange cars are adjacent.  Hence, there are $6! - 5!2!$ arrangements in which they are not adjacent.

If the yellow car is parked at one of the two ends, there are $5!$ ways of parking the other cars.  Hence, there are $6! - 2 \cdot 5!$ arrangements in which a yellow car is not parked at either end.

There are $3$ ways to pick which pink car will be at the left end and $2$ ways to pick which of the remaining pink cars will be at the right end.  For each such choice, there are $4!$ ways of parking the other four cards.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4!$ arrangements in which a pink car is parked at each end of the row.

Answer (score 0):

a. If the pink cars must be park together? - my answer is $4!3!$ or $144$. Treat the $3$ pink cars as a single object.  You have $4$ objects, the pink cars as a whole the two orange cars, the $1$ yellow so there are $4!$ ways to order them.  There are then $3!$ ways to order the pink cars, so, as you say, $3!4!$ ways to do this.

b. If the orange cars must not be parked together? There are, of course, $6!= 720$ ways to park $6$ cars with no conditions.  There are, as above, $5!2!= 240$ ways to park the cars with the $2$ orange cars parked together so there are $6!- 5!2!= 480$ ways to park the cars with the orange cars not together.

c. If you can't park the yellow on either end? There are $5$ non-yellow cars so $5$ choices for the car on the left.  There are $4$ non-yellow cars left so $4$ choices for the car on the right.  There are now $4$ cars left, including the yellow car which can be parked in any of the $4$ places left so $4!$ ways to park those.  There are $5(4)(4!)= 480$ ways to do this.

d. If a pink car must be on both ends? With a pink car on each end, there are $4$ cars left which can be parked in any of the remaining $4$ places- there are $4!= 24$ ways to do that.

Comment: Your answer to part (d) is incomplete since you have not taken into account the number of ways the pink cars on either end can be selected.  Otherwise, your work looks good.

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts (seven out of 8 answers you posted yesterday!) need heavy editing.